# activate add class after running an animate in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div witch sensitive to mouse click . when user click on this div it will run an animation and go to the top of page. I want to activate a class after running this  animation to another div here it is my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".data-lock").click(function() {
          $(this).animate({
              bottom: '50%'
          });
          $("back-img").addClass("lock-up");
          setTimeout(function() {
              $(".data-lock").animate({
                  bottom: '0'
              });
              $("back-img").removeClass("lock-up");
          }, 30000);
      });
  });
```

Comment: And your question is... ? Please explain what goes wrong with your current code, and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Maybe you could provide the relevant HTML and CSS, but just enough for us to be able to reproduce the problem, nothing more

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".data-lock").click(function() {
          $(this).animate({
              bottom: '50%'
          }, function() {
              $("back-img").addClass("lock-up");
          });
          
          setTimeout(function() {
              $(".data-lock").animate({
                  bottom: '0'
              }, function() {
                   $("back-img").removeClass("lock-up");
              });
          }, 30000);
      });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method can receive a complete method, which is invoked after the animation finishes:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".data-lock").click(function() {
          $(this).animate({
              bottom: '50%'
          }, function() {
              $("back-img").addClass("lock-up");

              setTimeout(function() {
                  $(".data-lock").animate({
                      bottom: '0'
                  }, function() {
                     $("back-img").removeClass("lock-up");
                  });
              }, 30000);
          });
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) has an optional `complete` function callback that can be provided for the finishing of the animation.

> **complete**
>
> Type: Function()
>
> A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched >element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".data-lock").click(function() {
          $(this).animate({
              bottom: '50%'
          }, function() {
              $("back-img").addClass("lock-up");
          });
          
          setTimeout(function() {
              $(".data-lock").animate({
                  bottom: '0'
              }, function() {
                   $("back-img").removeClass("lock-up");
              });
          }, 30000);
      });
});
```